# Change color of UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

If I use the UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel, it's color is set to that of the navigation bar. However, in the Photos App, the "Cancel" button is shown with a blue background. How can I also set the UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel to have a blue background please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your can use image as button image as

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

//create the button and assign the image
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


//create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
//UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickActionItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button ];




self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: if you want to place bar button item in left ,u can do that from self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=urbarbutton variable.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is a good workaround but I was hoping this would be possible without a workaround

Answer (score 2):

set the theNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent

```
theNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

and the buttons will be blue by default.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a custom tintcolor for the navbar. I tried this but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way than using an image. The UISegmentedControl can be configured to look just like a UIBarButtonItem and UISegmentedControl has a tintColor property.

```
UISegmentedControl *button = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:itemTitle, nil]] autorelease];
    button.momentary = YES;
    button.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    button.tintColor = color;
    [button addTarget:theTarget action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    UIBarButtonItem *removeButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
```

I built a [UIBarButtonItem category](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/03/31/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-uibarbuttonitem/) that'll do this.