# UINavigationItem setTint Bug?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I think this is a bug with the way apple is changing the tint color:

This is the code that i am using :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(dismiss)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

and later, on button tap :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = nil;
}];
```

Doesn't matter what color i put there, the effect is same.

[The undesired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZv8R.jpg)

Comment: Try to read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919614/change-color-of-uibarbuttonsystemitemcancel

Comment: what did u written in dismiss method .

Comment: I am not tapping on it, i am tapping on another button that causes the TintColor to change.

Comment: @AlexandruDranca when tap on other button. Its changing tint color to blue because it is default color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting colors for diferent states?

```
[[theNavigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[theNavigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```